# Jcarousel - display last image first in the infinite loop

Tags: jquery, loops, jcarousel, carousel

I'm wondering if anyone using Jcarousel would have a suggestion on how to clone or display the very last image of the carousel as the first image.

Example of 5 photos where the carousel shows 3 images it currently looks like this:

1 - 2 - 3 (4 and 5 are waiting to be shown)

Instead, here is what I am trying to achieve on load:

5 - 1 - 2 (3 and 4 are waiting to be shown)

What I am using at the moment is the following settings:

wrap: 'circular',
scroll: 1,
auto: 1,

I have tried an offset: -1 but this shows a blank and does not work.

I have also tried an offset to start the carousel with the last image - however, with wrap set to 'circular' this also does not work and makes other images blank until you manually load them.

I have done my best to look for an answer on my own but would appreciate your help, thanks in advance.

EDIT: I'm also open to suggestions of a different script that can do this - thanks!

EDIT #2: Thank you first of all to those commenting. Further research: I have found this site (www.anothermag.com) does a fine job of showing the last image first which I believe is using Jquery SerialScroll based on the code. I have yet to try this but does seem very promising. Another idea I have is to see if I can make the last image show as the first in the Wordpress Loop so that it still uses Jcarousel but hardcodes the last image. Will post more updates.

EDIT #3: final solution:

I have chosen the answer below by Sparky672 since I think it's safe to say Jcarousel as of today is not capable of doing this without intervening with rearranging images before it loads.

However, in case anyone is interested in an option/alternative, I will be using Fred HQ's excellent script "Roundabout". The example I will be using is here: http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout/demo/around

With a few small modifications, it will do exactly what I need without much work in the loading part.

The settings would be to set opacity to 1 for all images, set tilt to 0, add auto-scroll in set interval, set size of the boxes to same size.

This particular carousel requires a white divider so I will be using the "Moving things around things" example to make the "thing" in the middle a white box to hide what is being looped behind.

I hope this helps someone.

Thanks again!

Comment: Regarding your latest edit:  It would be best to keep your question specific and not start going off-topic with too many follow-up questions.  Your original post is about jCarousel so anything else should really be posted as a separate question as long as it's not a duplicate of this one.  [Read this to learn more about how to ask questions here](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Comment: Not a problem at all... this is a high quality site because of community-moderation and all these rules.  Anyway, welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing these blank images because you're using a broken option.  jCarousel is a great script but even the developer acknowledges that `wrap:circular` [is not working](https://github.com/jsor/jcarousel/issues/search?q=circular).  The developer's own [demo shows the circular wrap issue](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_circular.html) (depends on the browser).  He's been [talking about fixing it](https://github.com/jsor/jcarousel/issues/206) for several months now.  I still use the plugin but I just don't use `wrap:circular` option.

> EDIT: I'm also open to suggestions of a different script that can do
>   this - thanks!

You can try [jCarousel Lite](http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/) as an alternative.  I've used jCarousel Lite when I wanted a circular wrap.

Comment: Thanks very much for the link to issues with Jcarousel's circular - I was unaware of this and had been happily using it for some time... I'll give jCarousel Lite a try to see if cloning the last image is possible. Thank you

Comment: @Chumtarou:  Also try changing the initial order of the images rather that forcing the clone where one may not be needed.

Comment: Very good point indeed - I'm currently testing that out trying to find a way to make the 5th post of the loop jump to the first spot - haven't found an answer to that one yet. I'm also going to try out SerialScroll as that looks very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

jCarousel Lite cannot do what you want out of the box.

To make a slideshow with 3 images visible circular, it clones the first 3 and the last 3 images. See default config demo: http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/#demo

This means you'll need to modify the order of the images *before* you initiate the plugin.

Comment: The OP is not using [jCarousel Lite](http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/)... he's using [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/).

Comment: You suggested jCarousel Lite as an alternative. Either way he/she will still have to modify the order of the images before calling the plugin.

Comment: Thank you both - I'll give jCarousel Lite a try - I've just also found Jquery SerialScroll as an alternative. Going to edit my comment above with a site showing exactly what I'm looking for in a moment.

Comment: marissa.c, You posted an answer to the OP's question so I just thought it was a little unusual that you're actually responding to mine.

Comment: I wanted to provide additional information about jCarousel Lite given that the OP would likely use that script instead after you highlighted the circular wrap issue in jCarousel.

Comment: I'm sure I'm using this site incorrectly with too many comments but wanted to just say "thanks!". I have added the final method to my madness above in edit 3. Cheers!

Comment: marissa, your help is appreciated... I just wanted to highlight that your answer may have been better as a direct comment on my answer or the original post.  Yes @Chumtarou, keeping comments on-topic and to a minimum is always best.